# Override property of the base class with a derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, polymorphism

In a C# code, if the `Rebar` class derives from `Reinforcement` class and the `RebarShape` class inherits the `ReinforcementShape` class. Is it possible to override the property `ReinforcementShape` in the base class with the `RebarShape` class?

```
   public class ReinforcementShape
   {
   }

   public class RebarShape : ReinforcementShape
   {
   }

   public class Reinforcement
   {
        public ReinforcementShape Shape { get; set; }
   }


   public class Rebar : Reinforement
   {
        // I want to override the Shape property
        // but with its derived class which is RebarShape

        // override the base property somehow!
        public RebarShape Shape { get; set; }
   }
```

**Update:**

What is wrong with the current implementation?

**In base:**

```
public virtual ReinforcementShape Shape { get; set; }
```

**In derived:**

```
public new RebarShape Shape { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can't override a property and change it's return type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this with generics, no need to override the base-class member:

```
public class Reinforcement<T> where T: ReinforcementShape 
{
    public <T> Shape { get; set; }
}

public class Rebar : Reinforement<RebarShape>
{
}
```

Now you can easily create an instance of `ReBar` and access its `Shape`-property which is an instance of `RebarShape`:

```
var r = new Rebar();
r.Shape = new RebarShape();
```

An attemp to assign an instance of `ReinforcementShape` to that property will cause a compile-time error, only a `RebarShape` is valid at this point.

EDIT: as per your edit. You can only override a member by overriding it´s implementation, not it´s return-value. So using `virtual` won´t do anything in your case. However as R.Rusev already mentioned you only need the `new`-keyword on your derived member, which will actually provide a completely new member which has the same name as that one from your base-class. But actually it is a completely different member which thas nothing in common with the former one. However when you write the following

```
Reinforcement r = new Rebar();
// assign value to Shape
var shape = r.Shape;
```

the original implemenation is used, not your neew one. So `shape` would be of type `ReinforcementShape` instead of `RebarShape`. The only way around this is to declare `r` as `Rebar` in the first place:

```
Rebar r = new Rebar();
// assign value to Shape
var shape = r.Shape;
```

But this is quite confusing to any user of your application and maybe to yourself also. I´d generelly not recommend to use that keyword. Better use the first approach.

EDIT: C#9 has the ability of covariant return-types on members. This way you can just use `public RebarShape Shape { get; set; }` in your `ReBar`-class.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use generics. Because I need to do this for several properties of these classes.

Comment: @Vahid: then you should add the other properties to your question. In general, generics is the better way to do it (compared to the `new` keyword answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `new` keyword to do it. So your definition of Rebar class will look like this.

```
public class Rebar : Reinforement
{
    public new RebarShape Shape
    {
        get { return (RebarShape)base.Shape; }
        set { base.Shape = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `new`-keyword does not *override*, but *hide* the base-class´ implementation. Anyway even with the keyword when you use your instance of the derived class as a variable of the base class the original member is used, not the new one.

Comment: Thanks. can you please also show me the the implementation in the base class. I want to be able to set in the base class as well.

Comment: @Vahid The base class remains the same.

Comment: @HimBromBeere You are right. I just though that's what Vahid want to do. So he doesn't have to cast RebarShape every time when he uses Rebar.