# Override property of an abstract base class with a derived class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, properties, polymorphism

I have a base class Building which is abstract and contains a BuildingSO property. I would like this property to be overriden by some of the subclasses, like this:

[image]

From a similar question ([Override property of the base class with a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268826/override-property-of-the-base-class-with-a-derived-class)) I realized that I could use generics by doing:

```
public class Building<T> where T: BuildingSO {
     public T BuildingSO { get; set; }
}

public class SpawningSO : Building<SpawningSO> {

}
```

But this seems a bit verbose, since every time I reference the Building class in any other classes, I have to explicitly declare the property type:

```
private Building<BuildingSO>> building;
```

Which in addition, depending on how the project is organised, seems to me like it coud lead to coupling between the BuildingSO/SpawningBuildingSO namespace and every other module that references Building.

So I was wondering if there could be another solution, especially since the question I got the answer from deals with a non-abstract base class. I wondered if the fact that my base class is abstract could somehow allow a more flexible solution.

Edit: also, I am working with Unity game engine, and I just learned another reason for which I can't use this generics approach: Unity doesn't support generic classes inheriting from MonoBehaviour and in my example, Building has to inherit from MonoBehaviour.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this concrete approach will not work because `SpawningBuilding : Building<SpawningSO>` is not `Building<BuildingSO>` and you will not be able to assign an instance of former to the latter - [here explained why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/886368/2501279). If you are willing to make the property readonly - you can leverage [covariant returns introduced in C# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns):

```cs
public class BuildingSO
{
}

public class SpawningSO : BuildingSO
{
}

public class Building
{
    public virtual BuildingSO BuildingSO { get; }
}


public class SpawningBuilding :Building
{
    public SpawningBuilding(SpawningSO buildingSo)
    {
        BuildingSO = buildingSo;
    }
    public override SpawningSO BuildingSO { get; }
}
```

Also can be useful:

- [Variance in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)